# Comparing row values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Ok so I'm trying to solve a challenge that says I have to add weight to a graph's edges.
I am open to choosing what ever I want as my weight and I choose to add 1 each time I found a duplicated row in the Data frame.
The problem is as in this data set: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/csanhueza/the-marvel-universe-social-network?select=hero-network.csv (hero network)
we have several rows with 2 columns, I have to find a way to compare each row with another one, and if I found a value more than once add a 1 as its weight. As for .duplicated() function, I know as a fact that there are more rows with the same 2 heroes connected to each other
So my problem is I don't really know how to do it.
any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many times every unique row appears in a DataFrame, it can be done by using groupby:

```
df.groupby(by=['hero1','hero2']).size()
```

Explanation: `groupby` creates groups of distinct rows; `size()` counts how many rows exist in each group.

A more general solution, works for every number of columns in a DataFrame:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thanks for your response, I'm now trying to have unique values on the contrary I'm trying to count how many times every of two columns of heroes (hero 1 and hero 2) appeared in the rows and use it as a weight for my edges when I'm creating a graph with networkX

Comment: My English is not the best; I'm still not sure I fully understand what result you are pursuing. Could you please post a small example of the input data and of the expected result?  You can find guidance on creating a minimal example in the help centre: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but it seems to be what you are asking for. The code is "comparing rows" but it seems like what you are asking for is just summing the number of the same name in each column. I've included that as well using value_counts().

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#make a datafram with 2 columns, one and two, filled with letters. some match, some don't.
one=['a','b','c','d','a','a','a','b','f','g']
two=['a','b','c','a','b','c','g','g','f','f']
weight=np.ndarray.tolist(np.zeros(len(one)))
data1 = {'one': one, 'two': two,'weight': weight}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
#df1.iat[i,1]) ==> how to index down the right hand column
for i in range(len(one)):
    if df1.iat[i,1]==df1.iat[i,0]:
        df1.iat[i,2] = int(1)
    else:
        df1.iat[i,2]=None
print(df1)

df2=pd.DataFrame({'one': one, 'two': two})
print(df2['one'].value_counts())
```

Comment: So the thing is, for example I have two hero names in a row that shows this two encounter each other in some way lets say "Iron man" and "Spider man";

I want to be able to count how many times this due ( which each hero name appeared in a different column , hero1 = Iron man and hero2 = Spider man) encounter each other in the data set and use this value as a weight, This is the part that I don't know how to do, I mean how to lock this two name to each other and search this due through whole rows of the data set.

Comment: Just to clarify: col1=h1, col2=h2, search entire data set for that orientation elsewhere, count them up